# difference between dowhile and do while in fortran90

Tags: matlab, fortran, conventions, do-while

In a f90 code there is the following section of a code

```
dowhile: do while <conditions>


 ....

end do dowhile
```

I never came across with such a loop, and I cannot understand what would be the difference if i omit the "dowhile ... end dowhile" and simply use a normal "do while" loop.

Can anybody here help me to clarify this point ?

If i have to convert this loop into a matlab, does the simple matlab while loop be sufficient ?

Many thanks

Comment: By "normal" i besicaly mean what essentially you wrote. What puzzles me is the "dowhile:" before the "do while". This is what confuses me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, now I think I got your question:

the `dowhile:` statement gives a label or name to the loop, and consequently the loop called `dowhile` is terminated using the `enddo` statement. You could have used a different name for the loop as well:

```
mainloop: do while <conditions>
  ! ...
enddo mainloop
```

This labeling is optional, you can leave it away.

The comments put up a good point: The use of `exit` or `cycle` with a label. You could prematurely `exit` or `cycle` the loop if it has a label. This is especially useful for nested loops:

```
outer: do while <condition>
  do i=1,10
    if <some condition> then
      cycle ! cycles the inner loop
    elseif <some other condition> then
      cycle outer ! cycles the outer loop
    endif
  enddo ! i
enddo outer
```

If such constructs are used, you cannot easily remove the loop names.

I don't think Matlab allows labeling loops, but I'm no expert on Matlab.

---

Original answer:

Well, the `do while` construct is essentially an infinite loop that is terminated if the `<conditions>` are true.

```
conv = .false.
do while ( conv .eqv. .true. )
  ! ... do stuff
enddo
```

corresponds to

```
conv = .false.
do
  if ( conv .eqv. .true. ) exit
  ! ... do stuff
enddo
```

This should be doable in Matlab as well. The Matlab syntax is [(taken from here)](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/while.html?searchHighlight=while):

```
while expression
   statements
end
```

As a side-note: I would define a *simple* `do`-loop as a finite loop, though...

```
do i=1,10
  ! ... do stuff
enddo ! i
```

This construct is *not* equivalent to the `do while`-loop.

Comment: Thanks, so the "dowhile: ... " just labels the "do while - loop" in that case why someone might want to label a particular while loop ? can fortran then "call" this particular labeled loop in order to be used somewhere else ?

Comment: labeling doesn't seem to have any utility different from commenting, unless maybe some compiler can use it to give better error reporting.

Comment: @george, labelling loops actually makes things like `EXIT outerloop` statements in inner loops possible.

Comment: Names are optional... except when they are used.  If there's a, say, `exit dowhile` then changing/deleting won't be nice.

Comment: Thanks - should have known that.. and it brings a good point the OP needs to be aware if there are `exits` using those labels.

Comment: @HristoIliev I updated the answer to reflect that usage. Thanks, I did not think of that...